# Check UIImageView array frame equality with NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, nsarray, nstimer

I am wondering how to check if all the frames of two `UIImageView` `NSMutableArray`s are equal to each other. Now I am using a `NSTimer` for that.

Here is the code which I used in the method:

```
__block BOOL equal = YES;
[Img1Array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIImageView *ImageView1, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    UIImageView *ImageView2 = Img2Array[idx];
    if (!CGRectEqualToRect(ImageView1.frame, ImageView2.frame)) {
        *stop = YES;
        equal = NO;
    }
}];

if (equal) {
    NSLog(@"ALL THE FRAMES ARE EQUAL");
    [AllPosCorrectTimer invalidate];
}
```

The method has a boolean in it as you can see. But every time the value of the 'equal' boolean is true because of the timer, so the frames are always equal to each other according to the if-statement.

The function has a boolean in it as you can see. But every time the value of the 'equal' boolean is true because of the timer, so the frames are always equal to each other according to the if-statement.

How can I make sure this method will work?

Answer (score 1):

The block is called a-synchronically, that means that the `if` statement will be called every time with the equal=YES.

Try using the regular enumeration:

```
- (void)startTimer {
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(checkTheFrames) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}  

- (void)checkTheFrames {
    BOOL allEquals = [self isEqualFrames]; 
    if (allEquals) {
        NSLog(@"ALL THE FRAMES ARE EQUAL");
        [self.timer invalidate];
    }   
}  

- (BOOL)isEqualFrames {
    for(int i=0; i < Img1Array.count; i++ ){
        UIImageView *ImageView1 = Img1Array[i];
        UIImageView *ImageView2 = Img2Array[i];
        if (!CGRectEqualToRect(ImageView1.frame, ImageView2.frame)) {
            return NO; // Stop enumerating
        }
    } 
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: So I have to put the if-statement under the other if-statement in the block?

Comment: Because that doesn't work. I get the `NSLog` multiple times when I move one `UIImageView`. I would like to have one `NSLog` when all frames of two `UIImageView` arrays are equal to each other

Comment: I wouldn't use the block enumeration in this case, I would just use the regular one. Checkout my updated answer.

Comment: I used your code, but that doesn't work. I immediately get the NSLog.

Comment: If you get the NSLog that means that one of the frames are not equal, are you sure they are all equal? (BTW, I had a mistake in the method, not sure if you copy it before I fix it, so try to copy again)

Comment: I mean the NSLog 'ALL FRAMES ARE EQUAL' And I used your updated code.

Comment: I don't understand, you say they are all equal, and that you get the NSLog (that means they equal) so what is the problem??

Comment: I have two layers. the bottom layer consists of hidden `UIImageView`s, the upper layer consists of visible `UIImageView`s. When all the frames of the bottom layer `UIImageView`s are equal to the frames of the upper layer `UIImageView`s, you have to see that with a `NSLog`.

Comment: If I understand you right, you move the visible frames and you want to know when they are equal to the hidden frames? If so, you need to call the 'isEqualFrames' method after every movement of the frames. Or you can use a timer (not the best solution here, but the easiest), and do the check every 100 ms for example

Comment: Yes, but how do I do that? I have tried several codes and all of them have never worked.

Comment: I updated the answer, just call startTimer once in viewDidLoad or any other place before you start moving the frames.

Comment: I still get the NSLog immediately

Comment: maybe they start with the same frames... I suggest you to update your question with the full code, else its hard to understand

Comment: It seems the boolean method always returns true.

Comment: I suggest you to debug the 'setPiecesImg' method, check if indeed it builds two not equals arrays of frames.