# Cannot determine when UIImageView frames are equal

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, frame

I have two layers. The bottom layer consists of hidden `UIImageView`s, the upper layer consists of visible `UIImageView`s. When all the frames of the bottom layer `UIImageView`s are equal to the frames of the upper layer `UIImageView`s, you have to see that in a `NSLog`.

The problem is that the boolean method which is called by a `NSTimer` always returns true immediately, so I see the `NSLog`. I only want to see the `NSLog` when all corresponding frames are equal to each other.

This is my code:

```
- (void)checkTheFrames {
    BOOL allEquals = [self isEqualFrames];
    if (allEquals) {
        NSLog(@"ALL THE FRAMES ARE EQUAL");
        [AllPosCorrectTimer invalidate];
    }
}

-(BOOL)isEqualFrames {
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayImg.count; i++ ){
        UIImageView *ImageView1 = arrayImg[i];
        UIImageView *ImageView2 = HiddenFieldView[i];
        if (!CGRectEqualToRect(ImageView1.frame, ImageView2.frame)) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: You should log the frames to make sure you're getting what you think you should in the isEqualFrames method.

Comment: I did, all the frames are equal when they have to be.

Comment: And how about when they're not supposed to be equal, have you logged them then?

Comment: Why do I have to do that?

Comment: Just for troubleshooting purposes. Your logic looks correct in the code you posted, so the only thing I can think of that would be wrong, is the data (frames) coming in to the method.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your method returns TRUE if all the respective frames are equal. What do you mean by *"always returns true immediately"*, and how is this related to the timer? - In other words: What result do you expect?

Comment: The frames are correct. I just logged them.

Comment: So you're saying that you can log frames that are not all equal, and you still get the method returning YES?

Comment: @MartinR The method only must return true when all the corresponding frames are equal to each other. When the timer calls the method, I immediately see the `NSLog`.

Comment: @rdelmar Yes, that's right. Very strange I know.

Comment: @Steven: But the function does exactly that. The method returns TRUE if all corresponding frames are equal, and FALSE otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I see the opposite.

Comment: Here is my main question where I have posted the whole code I am using now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770973/check-uiimageview-array-frame-equality-with-nstimer/17771226?noredirect=1#comment25924026_17771226

Comment: Could be a rounding error which isn't showing when you log the frames.   Try rounding the `CGRect` elements to a specified number of decimal places using the answer provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343890/rounding-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-c

Comment: Post the logs that you take and show how you changed the code to generate the logging.

Comment: I think you're going to have to post the actual app somewhere if you want to get an answer. I don't see anything wrong with the logic, or anything you posted in the main question.

Comment: @rdelmar Me neither. I explained the stuff that happens.

Comment: @Wain this is the NSLog I got:

2013-07-21 19:14:41.580 app2[14208:c07] ALL THE FRAMES ARE EQUAL
2013-07-21 19:14:42.661 app2[14208:c07] 27.968002 73.599998 - 27.968002 73.599998
2013-07-21 19:14:47.789 app2[14208:c07] 116.546005 73.599998 - 116.546005 73.599998
2013-07-21 19:14:50.677 app2[14208:c07] 205.124008 73.599998 - 205.124008 73.599998

Comment: 2013-07-21 19:14:54.998 app2[14208:c07] 116.546005 164.350006 - 116.546005 164.350006
2013-07-21 19:15:01.869 app2[14208:c07] 205.124008 164.350006 - 205.124008 164.350006
2013-07-21 19:15:13.381 app2[14208:c07] 116.546005 255.100006 - 116.546005 255.100006
2013-07-21 19:15:17.117 app2[14208:c07] 27.968002 255.100006 - 205.124008 164.350006
2013-07-21 19:15:19.181 app2[14208:c07] 205.124008 345.850006 - 205.124008 345.850006

Comment: This is the code I used to get the log:
NSLog(@"%f %f - %f %f", touch.view.frame.origin.x, touch.view.frame.origin.y, HiddenView2.frame.origin.x, HiddenView2.frame.origin.y);

Comment: Where are you logging this? Why are you logging touch.view.frame instead of ImageView1.frame like you have in your method above?

Comment: I am logging this when the touch ended of the UIImageView

Comment: I have posted the whole code in the main question

Comment: Are you sure `arrayImg` is not nil or empty? Did you initialize it and add objects to it?

Comment: @KurtRevis The array is not empty. It is filled with Uiimageviews

Comment: Your log should be:  NSLog(@"%f %f - %f %f", ImageView1.frame.origin.x, ImageView1.frame.origin.y, ImageView2.frame.origin.x, ImageView2.frame.origin.y); and it should be placed right before if (!CGRectEqualToRect(ImageView1.frame, ImageView2.frame)) in isEqualFrames. This is where you have the problem, so this is where you should do the log, and it should be done with the actual pointers that you're using in the comparison. Please do that, and report the results.

Comment: @rdelmar This is the log I got: http://we.tl/CcZGb8Esfl

Answer (score 1):

I think whats wrong is that you're comparing the Xs and Ys too... maybe you should go further to `frame.size` and compare them. Or maybe compare the widths and heights easily `(frame1.size.width == frame2.size.width)`

Let me know if this didn't solve the problem!

Comment: The size is a part of a frame. I don't know what you mean

Comment: @Steven Sorry, thought you just wanted to check the equality of sizes... So you need to compare the locations too? Are they on top of each other when you first fire the method?

Comment: The locations of the UIImageViews are next to each other.